# AWK-merge files based on key

Tags: awk

I have two files:

**1.txt**

```
jeden:AA 
dwa:BB 
trzy:CC 
cztery:DD 
piec:EE 
szesc:FF 
ttttttt:to 
siedem:GG 
osiem:HH 
dziewiec:II 
dziesiec:JJ
```

**2.txt**

```
JJ:jola 
EE:ela 
BB:baska 
FF:flora 
II:irga 
AA:adam 
to:llll 
DD:darek 
CC:celina 
HH:hela 
GG:gosia
```

I want to merge the two files based on key. Expected result:

```
jeden: adam 
dwa: baska 
trzy: celina 
cztery: darek 
piec: ela 
szesc: flora 
ttttttt: llll
siedem: gosia 
osiem: hela 
dziewiec: irga 
dziesiec: jola
```

I tried this:

```
$ awk -F ":" '{getline a < "2.txt" split(a, b, ":"); if($2==b[1]) print $1":", b[2]}' 1.txt 
ttttttt: llll
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
awk '
    BEGIN { 
        FS = "[: ]*"; 
        OFS = ":"; 
    } 
    FNR == NR { 
        keys[ $1 ] = $2; 
        next; 
    } 
    { 
        printf "%s%s %s\n", $1, OFS, ($2 in keys) ? keys[ $2 ] : "???"; 
    }
' 2.txt 1.txt
```

That yields:

```
jeden: adam
dwa: baska
trzy: celina
cztery: darek
piec: ela
szesc: flora
ttttttt: llll
siedem: gosia
osiem: hela
dziewiec: irga
dziesiec: jola
```

Comment: Thank you, good solution. Do you still write another solution using getline?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple steps.

```
$ gawk -F: '{print $2 " " $1}' 1.txt | sort > 1.1.txt
$ gawk -F: '{print $1 " " $2}' 2.txt | sort > 2.1.txt
$ paste -d' ' 1.1.txt 2.1.txt | gawk '{print $2 ": " $4}'
jeden: adam
dwa: baska
trzy: celina
cztery: darek
piec: ela
szesc: flora
siedem: gosia
osiem: hela
dziewiec: irga
dziesiec: jola
ttttttt: llll
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use coreutils `join` for this:

```
join -t: -1 2 -2 1 -o 1.1 2.2 \
  <(sort -t: -k2,2 1.txt | sed -r 's/\s+$//') \
  <(sort           2.txt | sed -r 's/\s+$//')
```

Result:

```
jeden:adam
dwa:baska
trzy:celina
cztery:darek
piec:ela
szesc:flora
siedem:gosia
osiem:hela
dziewiec:irga
dziesiec:jola
ttttttt:llll
```

If you really want the extra space after colon append `| sed 's/:/& /'` to the command